# Using AutoComplete in material-table

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-table

I have a material table with right farthest column as an AutoComplete (the business user really wants to have search capability because sometimes the option list is very long - thousands of values).
The two problems I have encountered are:

(1) When I click in (or tab into) the AutoComplete field, the previously selected value vanishes (a previous value is displayed).

(2) When I select an option, the combo list closes and row editing exits! (no check mark or X to complete/abandon row editing).  This ONLY happens with AutoComplete columns in a material-table.

I have a few code blocks:

Snippet showing material-table column definition:

```
    const itemMapTitles = {
        columns : [
            { title: 'Target Data Item', field: 'dropDown', width: "40%", 
                editComponent: props => {
                    console.log("first line props: ",props);
                    return (
                    <div>
                        <Autocomplete
                        value={props.value}     
                        inputValue={props.value}  
                        openOnFocus         
                        autoHighlight       
                        autoSelect          
                        clearOnEscape       
                        fullWidth
                        handleHomeEndKeys    
                        selectOnFocus        
                        disableCloseOnSelect="true"   // doesn't seem to work
                        getOptionLabel={option => option.tItemName}  
                        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.tItemName === value.tItemName }  
                        id="targetDataItem"
                        options={targetLeafItems1}  

                        renderInput={ (params) => (
                            <TextField
                                {...params}  //must stay
                                margin="normal"
                                defaultValue={props.rowData.tItemName}
                                fullWidth 
                                style={{ minWidth: 150 }}
                            />
                        )}

                        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                            console.log("From onChange: " + JSON.stringify(newValue));
                            console.log("props onChange: ", JSON.stringify(props));

                            setSelectedTarget( newValue );
                            
                            for(let i =0; i < mappingRows.length; i++) {
                                if ( mappingRows[i].tNodeKey === props.rowData.tNodeKey ) {
                                    console.log("Found it");

                                    //updating the array element in the material-table data
                                    if ( newValue === null ) {
                                        mappingRows[i].tNodeKey = null;
                                        mappingRows[i].tItemName = null;
                                        mappingRows[i].dropDown = null;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        mappingRows[i].tNodeKey = newValue.tItemName + "^" + newValue.tNodeKey;
                                        mappingRows[i].tItemName = newValue.tItemName;
                                        mappingRows[i].dropDown = newValue.tItemName;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }}
                        />
                    </div>
                    )
                },
                render: rowData => {  
                    return <div>{rowData.tItemName}</div>;
                }
            },
```

Snippet showing material-table in the react page:

```
                <MaterialTable
                        title="Data Item Level Mappings"
                        columns={itemMapTitles.columns}   //defined in previous snippet
                        data={mappingRows}
                        icons={IconSet}
                        tableRef={tableRef}
```

Snippet showing how mappingRows is populated (from the DB):

```
        axios.post(`/mapping/get/rows`)
            .then(res => {
            const rowData = res.data.map(item => {
                const rowobj = {};
                rowobj.tItemName = item.target_data_item_name;
                rowobj.tNodeKey = item.target_data_item_name + "^" + item.node_key;
                rowobj.dropDown = item.target_data_item_name;
                return rowobj;
            })
            setMappingRows( rowData );
```

Any advice on things to try to solve the two problems above would be really helpful.

Comment: A few views but no answers.  Is it because there's not enough details in the question? Or has no one encountered this situation?  Switch to another react table plugin?

Comment: Did you get passed the issue ?

Comment: Not yet.  But I will be re-examining this from scratch in Jan.  I will add an update if I make progress.